# Openerp - How can i call a function to run every time a specific view is called?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm working with the module products and stock of openerp. I have to update the products with an external database every time i enter a section that works with them. Currently i have a button to update, so the function is ready, i just need to find the right way to call the function either when i click on the menu item of products or when certain views are open.
Is this possible? And which way is better?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to call a function when view renders, you can override `fields_view_get` method of openerp. 
here is the example to override `fields_view_get`.

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context=None, toolbar=False, submenu=False):
    '''
    Your code
    '''
    return super(CLASS_NAME, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id, view_type, context, toolbar, submenu=submenu)
```

Comment: thank you so much! i put this in my products and my sales classes and everything is updating perfectly.